# Change user property after token validation

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware, auth0

I want to add extra properties to user from `Auth` facade.
I use Auth0 as service to login.
I think about add extra middleware to do it, but I don't know how run this middleware after `Auth0` valitadtion.

It is my first time wneh I do somethink like that so I'll be happy if someone tell me what I should read first do solve this.